# Eclipse xmlFiles content is not allowed in prolog error

Tags: xml, spring, eclipse

[image]

All xml files line 1 show error log show content is not allowed in prolog 
it's just create a Project no edit anything. 
check none utf-8bom
and delete project even does reset program

Comment: Create what kind of project? Maybe the thing creating the project has a bad bug.

Comment: This can have different reasons, which cannot be seen from the screenshot, e. g. a [zero-width space character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) before the root element or a UTF-16 encoded file that is read as UTF-16BE (what text file encoding do you have in right-click + _Properties: Resource: Text File Encoding_?).

Comment: no i naver use encoded UTF-16   i always used UTF-8 and first install my first job is change encoding UTF-8

Comment: UTF-16 vs. UTF-16BE was just an example. The text file encoding can be set on different levels: for the workspace, for a project, for a (sub)folder or for a single file.

Comment: Change the encoding how?

Comment: window Tap  Preferences Textbox your write encoding  you can change encoding

Comment: This preference does not change the bytes of existing files but is how the bytes are converted to characters when reading (and when adding/changing characters). This preference can be overwritten by the text file encoding setting of a folder. So moving a file to another location may change the text file encoding.

Answer (score 0):

It was That wasn't our intention. Change Directory it' will fix it 
I don't know what is reason anyway  thanx reply
someone  Anything do it but can't fix it maybe Change DIR